# I have a json which contains arrays of objects, which in turn are objects of a larger array. How do I go about reading this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I hope the title didn't confuse anyone, but I need it in this form so I can pass it in an api call for a JDE AIS application.

Here is what I am having trouble with:

When I simply import this using var json=require("./file.json") I get a unexpected syntax error. How do i actually go about reading this in node/javascript?

```js
{
  "final": [{
      "gridColumnEvents": [{
          "value": "1110-000",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 20
        },
        {
          "value": "Cash - Operating",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 21
        },
        {
          "value": "10.00",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 22
        },
        {
          "value": "map",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 23
        },
        {
          "value": "2019",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 24
        },
        {
          "value": "1",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 25
        },
        {
          "value": "map53511",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 26
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "gridColumnEvents": [{
          "value": "1116-000",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 20
        },
        {
          "value": "Cash in Trust",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 21
        },
        {
          "value": "10.00",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 22
        },
        {
          "value": "map",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 23
        },
        {
          "value": "2019",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 24
        },
        {
          "value": "1",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 25
        },
        {
          "value": "map53511",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 26
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "gridColumnEvents": [{
          "value": "1170-000",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 20
        },
        {
          "value": "Petty Cash",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 21
        },
        {
          "value": "10",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 22
        },
        {
          "value": "map",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 23
        },
        {
          "value": "2019",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 24
        },
        {
          "value": "1",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 25
        },
        {
          "value": "map53511",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 26
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "gridColumnEvents": [{
          "value": "1200-000",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 20
        },
        {
          "value": "Accounts Receivable",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 21
        },
        {
          "value": "10.00",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 22
        },
        {
          "value": "map",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 23
        },
        {
          "value": "2019",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 24
        },
        {
          "value": "1",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 25
        },
        {
          "value": "map53511",
          "command": "SetGridCellValue",
          "columnID": 26
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:
The error code I am getting is unexpected token : at final :**

Comment: Can you give out the detailed context about your environment? I just tried to require your JSON file, it works well. i use  node v10.15.3.

Comment: i am using node v11.10. All i am doing is                                                             
var jsonobj=require("./TEN_2019_03.JSON");     then trying to console.log the jsonobj

Comment: @SteveGao I get a unexpected token : at final :

Comment: So we are on the same page, create a new Node.JS file named **main.js** then make a **data.json** file. In the main.js file add `let data = require('./data');` without the ***.json*** and then `console.log(data);`. Tell me if that gives you the same error, after running main.js with `node main.js`

Comment: @Raymond i put the file name in place of "./data" correct? if so I get the same error. What I did notice was, if i JUST copied the contents of this file (same json as initial post) and just pasted into a different .json file it works

Comment: You had some extra characters. Always revert back to environment changes and start over if you are getting unexpected results. Chances are something was pressed as a keystroke by mistake. Glad you have it working.